# AFWall (Firewall) : unblock ADB wireless

Tags: android, adb, firewall

How to enable ADB wireless in case you have a Firewall (as AFWall)? Just adding adb to the whitelist seems not enough.
Is it that I have to open the port 5555? I am a noob in configure a FW without GUI and there is no option for this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Arno's solution didn't work for me, but the following custom script did, which I found on [AFWall's official wiki](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/wiki/CustomScripts#droidwall-only-examples) (I only modified the name of the iptable chain):

```
# Temporarily allow network adb access when you need it at port 5555 (for Android Studio 5005)
ADB_UID=10004
SHELL_UID=2000
SAFE_NETWORK=192.168.0.0/24

# Allow adb (port 5555)
$IPTABLES -I "afwall" -s $SAFE_NETWORK -p tcp --dport 5555 -j RETURN
$IPTABLES -I "afwall" -m owner --uid-owner $ADB_UID -d $SAFE_NETWORK -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -p tcp --sport 5555 -j RETURN
$IPTABLES -I "afwall" -m owner --uid-owner $SHELL_UID -d $SAFE_NETWORK -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -p tcp --sport 5555 -j RETURN

# Remove transproxy for adb output
$IPTABLES -t nat -I OUTPUT -d $SAFE_NETWORK -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -p tcp --sport 5555 -j ACCEPT
```

You'll still need to adjust `SAFE_NETWORK`, which can also be only an IP address.

---

**Bonus**: if you happen to use [scrcpy-android](https://gitlab.com/las2mile/scrcpy-android) (i.e., mirror the screen to another Android device), you also have to open port 7007 in the third iptables call, like so:

```
$IPTABLES -I "afwall" -m owner --uid-owner $SHELL_UID -d $SAFE_NETWORK -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -p tcp -m multiport --sport 5555,7007 -j RETURN
```

(note the added `-m multiport` and `,7007`)

Answer (score -1):

Get a good hint in another forum: adding a custom script with this line solves the issue:

```
/system/bin/iptables -A "afwall-wifi" -d <IP_of_PC> -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner <UID_of_ADB_service> -m tcp -j ACCEPT
```